# mount truecrypt volumes using system encryption passphrase

Tags: fedora, password, startup, truecrypt

From a previous Windows setup I have two Truecrypt encrypted harddrives. I can mount these without any problem during my fedora session with:

```
sudo /sbin/cryptsetup open --type tcrypt /dev/sdb2 stuff
sudo /sbin/cryptsetup open --type tcrypt /dev/sdb2 otherstuff
```

I have automated this process with the help of https://meinnoteblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/14/truecrypt-container-mit-cryptsetup-automatisch-mounten-und-unmounten/. However, this is stil a bit tedious as I have to type the same passphrase is a bit long and I have to type it twice. I could just write a script storing my passphrase but this would be a vulnerability as the script can be read by anyone. I thought about storing the passphrase in the keyring, but I prefer not to save the passphrase on the pc. Additionally I have no Idea how to do this because I only found an [incomplete tutorial for Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Dm-crypt%2FMounting_at_login&type=revision&diff=425842&oldid=425740).

Since I use the same passphrase for the truecrypt drives as I do for the system drive, I wonder if I can mount these during startup with the passphrase to unlock the system partition. I run Fedora and any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. I have previously [asked this on Ask Fedora](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/93269/mount-truecrypt-volumes-using-system-encryption-passphrase/) with no response.

Comment: So... you don't want to enter the passphrase yourself each time because it's too long. But you also don't want to save the passphrase on the PC. What would be acceptable?

Comment: I dont want to enter the passphrase multiple times. I already enter it during startup because I have luks system encryption turned on. I want to use this passpharase to unlock the truecrypt devices.

Comment: If you have one encrypted partition that you always mount first, you could store keys for the other partitions on that first partition